# Run feature file with cucumber java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Im trying to run a simple feature file with java and intellij and I cant seem to get it working.

Ive set up my Cukes test runner class

```
package config;

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(monochrome = true,
    features = {"src/test/resources/features/"},
    dryRun = false,
    glue = "com.ecs.googleuat"
)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

feature:
Feature: home
  Scenario: home
    Given I am on the home page

step definitions:

```
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class MyStepdefs {
@Given("^I am on the home page$")
public void iAmOnTheHomePage() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
}
```

project structure:

[image]

Im using a maven project with the java cucumber plugins.

When I run the feature file I get the following error:

Undefined step: Given  I am on the home page

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
1 Steps (1 undefined)
0m0.000s

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
@Given("^I am on the home page$")
public void i_am_on_the_home_page() throws Throwable {
// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
throw new PendingException();
}
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Please help me understand what Im doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: what is the glue `com.ecs.googleuat`?

Comment: can you add a, image of the expanded project structure especially the java part?

Comment: @VinayPrajapati this is the groupID, i thought that was the glue, I'm obviously wrong

Comment: After removing the groupId what error is it giving?

Comment: The same error, the step definitions cant be found

Comment: this means that cucumber is unable to find your glue. try creating a directory inside your src/test/java and appending that to the location provided in your runner `glue = "com.ecs.googleuat"`

Comment: @Marit, this works!! thank you!! Why does this work though, When I use the cucumber to create the step defs, it works fine. Why cant it find it where it was automatically created?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but I think the issue is with the method name. The easy solution just copy-paste the suggested step definition inside `MyStepdefs` and remove exception and add your `println` and then run. Also try removing the glue `com.ecs.googleuat` you added.

Please follow [this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) for further help!

Though I would strictly recommend going ahead with `java-8`.

Anyways, If you are comfortable with `Java-8`. Remove the glue in`RunCukesTest.java`. And update your `MyStepdefs.java`

```
  public class MyStepdefs implements En {
      public Stepdefs() {
        Given("^I am on the home page$", () -> {
           System.out.println("Hello");
        });
     }
 }
```

`En` automatically implements default Glue for you.

Also, use appropriate dependencies. Follow [this](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm) for same.

**Edit:**
For Java 8 please make sure that if you are using IntelliJ Idea, then Project SDK is enabled to `1.8`.

[image]

Comment: So I switched to jdk 1.8 and the method throws some errors. En needs to be implemented, Stepdefs requires a return type and the given steps needs a method call to be expected

Comment: I have put an example above did you try same?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, yes I tried your suggested method after switching to jdk 1.8 It gave me the errors I stated previously. Thanks

Comment: C:\dev\javalab\googleuat\src\test\java\MyStepdefs.java
Error:(5, 12) java: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(6, 45) java: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

Comment: You are using intelli J Idea? It means that java used by you is still not 1.8 version. So, I have edited my answer for what you need to change in Idea.

Comment: Thanks Alot, I tried that already though and the 1.8 jdk set and language level set to 8 already

Comment: @Marit, thanks for the update, I went down to 1.8 and Im still getting the issues

Comment: @mogoli I will then publish a working code on git repo and you could use that as base.